# What is "fuzz" in applying patches?

Tags: patch, quilt

I was applying a patch with quilt in Debian packaging that an error occurred:

```
Applying patch debian/patches/fixshare.patch
patching file net/slirp.c
Hunk #1 FAILED at 529.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- rejects in file net/slirp.c
```

I googled it and I've understood that this error is because of "Fuzz" in applying patches. Now, my question is what's fuzz and how can I solve my problem in applying quilt patches?

I've read [this article](https://wiki.debian.org/Projects/DebSrc3.0) and did the steps that it told, but still I have problem!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing

Comment: @DisplayName - it's not that, it's the _"fuzz factor"_ (`man patch`). @Mehrmaz - are you sure it's because of "fuzz" ? What was the next line after `1 out of 1 hunk FAILED` ?

Comment: @don_crissti : 
Applying patch debian/patches/fix-share.patch
patching file net/slirp.c
Hunk #1 FAILED at 529.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- rejects in file net/slirp.c
Patch debian/patches/fix-share.patch can be reverse-applied

Comment: @Mehrnaz - `patch can be reverse-applied` means the patch is already included or same changes were made to the source code. You should get rid of it (e.g. `quilt delete -r fix-share.patch`). Read [here](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2012/08/08/how-to-use-quilt-to-manage-patches-in-debian-packages/) for more details.

Comment: @don_crissti thanks! but here `quilt delete` is not a good solution, because by using that, removed patch went back again!

Comment: You used `-r`, e.g. `quilt delete -r` and the patch still applies ? Revert all patches: `quilt pop -a`, remove the unwanted one: `quilt delete -r fix-share.patch` and reapply the rest: `quilt push -a`.

Answer (score 8):

This is not necessarily due to fuzz (in particular if you have refreshed the patches as told in the [article](https://wiki.debian.org/Projects/DebSrc3.0)). It may happen that the source has changed in such a way that patches are completely out of date. For instance, the original source was:

```
aa
bb
cc
```

and a patch told: replace line `bb` by `dd` (with some context, ignored here). Then the source changed to:

```
aa
bbb
cc
```

The patch still says: replace line `bb` by `dd`, but line `bb` no longer exists, so that the patch can no longer be applied successfully.

The solution is to look at the failed hunk, at the corresponding part of the old source (on which the patch could be applied), and try to see what has changed in the new source, then try to adapt the new source to regenerate the patch. This can only be done manually, and when there have been major changes in the source, this can be difficult, if not impossible.